# Could not inaltall next js in my computer

Tags: next.js

[image]

hello everyone, Please help me on this.
After I install next js all depandensis installed but npm run dev not showing

i follow th was same as documentation.

Comment: Seems like it is up and running at `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

In your console run `npm run dev`. The `npm run` part is an npm command that tells it to run a script. In your `package.json` you have a script called `dev` so you simply add the name of the script, `dev` after `npm run` and it will run that script.